# Fulfilling differing Android / iOS UI conventions from a single React Native codebase?

Tags: user-interface, mobile, user-experience, react-native

Is this even possible?

Every overview / analysis of React Native I've found covers the basic reasons for using RN, and is either old (no Android, or "Android just released") or focuses on the fact that it compiles to native elements (ie. not HTML5)

What I'm missing is, how does an app built in React Native fulfill the style guides, conventions, and user expectations of how apps on each platform are supposed to behave? I don't want to make an Android app that looks like an iOS app, or vise versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jevakallio answered you can customize you UI to platform specific rules from Google or Apple.
Technically it can be done in several ways. If differences are small you can make conditional check with `Platform` module:

```
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

If differences are big then use file postfix (`android` or `ios`):

```
MyComponent.ios.js
MyComponent.android.js
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html

You even can make full different UI for each platform or device type (tablet or phone) saves all non-UI logic common.

Answer (score 1):

The seminal resources for platform-specific style and interaction guides are the [Material Design system for Android](https://material.google.com/) and the [Human Interface Guidelines for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/).

Implementing iOS-feeling UX on React Native is quite simple out of the box. Android apps may benefit from using [react-native-material-design](http://react-native-material-design.github.io/) package to get native feeling controls.

One of the biggest challenges for web developers coming to mobile development via React Native (I am one) is to know what makes *that native feel*. This is a very subjective and touchy-feely topic, and cannot be easily solved by reading guides or applying logical engineering mindset to the problem.

I have found that using tons of popular apps and trying to reason about what makes them tick is a invaluable practice for this, as is critically evaluating your own work and putting time and care to details, as sometimes that is what makes all the difference.

Comment: Thanks. Was looking for confirmation / how to actually implement those differences, assuming my designers were aware of what they should be.